# How to render a template with URL params & anchor properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, view, rendering, render

In a controller, I need to render the template for another controller/action pair. Basically what happens is that I have a `RequestController` with a `create` action that  it creates, passes work to another controller to process the payment. If the payment does NOT go through, the user needs to be taken back to the `create` template to try again.

The complexity is that I can't just render the `create` template, because the form that the user suggested is at the bottom of the page and normally hidden. I need to render the template at the bottom of the page (the anchor) with a URL variable that indicates the form should not be hidden (show=true).

Something like this:

```
render "staticpages/#{params[:page_name]}?show=true#rent"
```

The problem is that when I do this, I get the error:

```
Missing template staticpages/outdoors?show=true#rent
```

So I tried passing the necessary variables as such:

```
render "staticpages/#{params[:page_name]}", anchor: "rent", show: "true"
```

But that didn't work either, any thoughts?

Comment: I want to ask few question before I write an answer. Try something like this:
create a `create.js.erb` file in controller A where the action create is happening.
Then inside that the views of that other Controller do something like this:
`<%= link_to "", purchase_path, :data => { :'class' => 'displayLink' }, :remote => true %>`

and then this renders the view from controller A

Comment: @Observer sorry, can you say that one more time? I got a bit lost...

Comment: @james It'd be very useful if you posted the complete code for the controller actions involved. `render` won't take any URL params or anchor, so you need to do it in a different way.

Comment: Why are you trying to do something dynamic in a file placed in the "staticpages" directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per @sjaime's comment that render can't take variables like that, this was much easier... i just didnt' know that lol

all I did was set

```
@error = true
render "staticpages/#{params[:page_name]}"
```

And then in the view, use JS:

```
if ('<%= @error =>' === 'true' ) {
  // show something
  // scroll to something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I have to change the layout on a controller what I like to do is:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  layout :choose_layout
  ... 
  def choose_layout
    if condition
      'layout/a'
    else
      'layout/b'
    end
  end
end
```

This way I can change the layout when a condition is meet